Push Notifications Not Working After Migration to HTTP v1 API
We recently migrated our push notifications from the Legacy HTTP API to the HTTP v1 API. Since then, push notifications are not working on either iOS or Android devices. Although FCM returns a "success" response, the messages are not being received by the devices.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have any ideas about what could be causing this?
Here's what we have done so far:
Migrated to the HTTP v1 API following the Firebase documentation.
Verified the entire code, especially the admin.messaging() module from the Firebase Admin SDK (we're using the send() method).
No errors or outages reported by FCM.
All relevant SDKs are up to date.
Tested whether low priority or message lifespan could be causing the issue – no success.
User devices are not in sleep mode and the app does not crash upon receiving the notification.
